# Why does GSC MutableListMultimap.get(K key) method return a "view" instead of a mutable collection?

Tags: gs-collections

While doing a `get()` on a `MutableListMultimap`, the list being returned is made unmodifiable (referring to code in `AbstractMutableMultimap#get()` ).

What is the thought process behind this ? If the collection being used as value in `Multimap` is of type `MutableList` wouldn't it make more sense to keep it that way ?

If not, what is the right way to modify that collection ?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of get() on Multimap (including a MutableListMultimap) is to provide a view of the values associated with the given key, not to modify the values collection.

If you wish to add or remove values associated with a key, you must use put(key, value) or remove(key, value).

Comment: In that case how are `MutableListMultimap` and `ImmutableListMultimap` different ? Does the Mutable or Immutable property apply to Multimap instead of the collection within ?

Comment: The ImmutableListMultimap doesn't provide methods like put() and remove().